# How to change values of private variables for all objects from under the same class?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

How to make the variable **`m_i`** have its own value for each object, and when a certain function is called, the value of **`m_i`** for all objects should be set to zero, no matter how many objects of the class **`CMyClass`** were created?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class CMyClass {
public:
   static int m_i;
};

int CMyClass::m_i = 0;
CMyClass myObject1;
CMyClass myObject2;

int main() {
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

   myObject1.m_i = 1; // set m_i to 1 for first object
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

   myObject2.m_i = 2; // set m_i to 2 for second object
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

   CMyClass::m_i = 0; // set m_i to zero for all objects
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;
}

Output

0
0
1
1
2
2
0
0
```

Expected output should be:

```
Output

0
0
1
0
1
2
0
0
```

**UPD**
The solution for MCU usage was proposed by @Lasersköld and works without any additionally libraries:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class CMyClass {
public:

    // The member variable should not be static because
    // it is unique for each class instance.
    int m_i;
};

CMyClass instances[2];

void resetInstances() {
    for (auto &instance: instances) {
        instance.m_i = 0;
    }
}

int main() {

   cout << instances[0].m_i << endl;
   cout << instances[1].m_i << endl;

   instances[0].m_i = 1;
   cout << instances[0].m_i << endl;
   cout << instances[1].m_i << endl;

   instances[1].m_i = 2;
   cout << instances[0].m_i << endl;
   cout << instances[1].m_i << endl;

   resetInstances();
   cout << instances[0].m_i << endl;
   cout << instances[1].m_i << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
1
2
0
0
```

Comment: You are aware what `static` exactly does, aren't you? Just remove that from the variable declaration.

Comment: Yes, but all my attempts to play around with private variables have failed

Comment: That doesn't have to do anything with `private`, you seem to confuse things.

Comment: Sorry, am still new to C++

Comment: Seem like you need a simple non-static public member variable?

Comment: Does public variable may has different value for all objects?

Comment: @OlegGolevych Again: `public` or `private` doesn't affect this. That's just for (in-)accessibility, from outside of the class.

Comment: Unfortunately I see only one way of accomplishing this output and you won't like what it does: Basically it replaces the type of the static member variable with an object that prints one int in a predetermined sequence of ints for each time `<<` operator is used: https://godbolt.org/z/xv3618vjT  To achive the logic you're actually trying to implement the `m_i` seen in the main function would need to both refer to a static and non-static member which is impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save each instance in a static list [like so](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGwAHKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAcEZWY4C4ZExLPGJKbaY9qUMQgRMxAR5Pn5BdQ05za0E5dFxCcmpCi1tHQXdEwNDldVjAJS2qF7EyOwc5kkRyN5YANQmSW5OE8SYrKfYJhoAgrv7h5gnZwBumA4kt/dPjy8WSMR2YbAUaSYWyOE3QpysjwOTAUCiObgAsgBPNwGFEnADsCIeaS8sVoeGQIH%2B/yOtLRWJxyIUEAiBCOeGWICOLAA%2BngTIT%2BfiACIEol0iXshhzBhbBQAOhJCgQPNiUIA1hACAg8AplvCaXSBcLqY8JQB6c1HAAqCDebCqCSOH1aeCYZLeyvWtHQoNQbPiMJajmQR3ioiBmENtMt7LZuqOXgYeAAjl43vxiEdrsgEEckXiIjKtvLo1K2bz%2BUkiWXY3MQ9zrtKjtqmGztW8XcQ3R6jgB3Oi0MNvDsw1gZkhHMS0WtWvnSlqyzAKHlHVBUKf53EKsv1ilB9AgEBfH7EU5uDHY7cAKluUuLy4Nj13wf3H1QeF9VyUBAgyzFZYSpmRwQEwXhECcZj%2BEWi5bFyMGGHK/4CuKkpoQhS4ALS3JW7yihoT4PGhtLGmWpHPiKhH/LCR4nkQZ5nJejIoreSTYPSV5MkeGFylRjystyTARH%2BAFmnSTHbtymIAPKxNo3wEFwKEEZR1ZHLGtoJgmAhvAWqLzg%2BgHEcZxGxoQRwIMim6oH2DDcnyzquu69BlhJTJSbJ8kOGYymkWpsbalpqKGP6dpZjxbzri2dpbkyppEbSaDge8bjnh5ckKVw8q4eeaWuDO1bRklbK5Wc6VeQQZjZQ5pVuNmDDoAVNZieVmXVXgeFHEphUtcVKVpSwMkZQ4WU5WceUNU1RXrCV41lYNnkKVVY2pWV%2BV8QlrXee1nU%2BT1m19bVW2KTtR3rftdKHXNdULcNlWndd9WNRtErRm5KJHt%2BmC/vqF2JTN/XzUNFWjTVj3nah%2BYA0dt0VctYOrXVEPUiKHCrLQnAAKy8H4HBaKQqCcKlljWDC6ybG8uw8KQBCaGjqzqiAmMaPonCSDjdME5wvAKCALO03jaOkHAsAwIgKCoCwaR0Ak5CUGgUsy4kwBcGYqRYB8FKYAAangmB9tJaSMJw1M0LQBAJLzECxJzsQRK0mIm7wCtsII0kMLQjuC6QWAsIYwDiN7%2BBXA4eBfLz3uYKo3zgds%2BOsvUnPkrExAOx4WCcwQ3YsE7qxUAYwAKLr%2BuG8b3C8PwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6je7oXD6P7KDWNY%2Bh4LEvOwGC7CxKgmQEKQXyJNwgRaMsqyoGkjQRzz9QKTkLgNdMfht2EETDI6iRt8U2QCJvehH40CwjAfPSrwI/RTJ4nR6HYt9NJMgy74soxt3MD/5Fvth36X33hIVYChyZwS4OjLGHNvaEw4EcVQgR/CYX8JII4wBkChlVvKMwIFcCEEnFTZYvABYzwZkzFmGMODs1IDnZmpBcb43gTzPmNM6arBFuLGaJIx4UAgAraW9BiBRHHJwJBKC0EYKwV1KqZheCYHwPRT8ehK7CFEOIOuajG5qE5q3UgfZU5pFzqzDg2NGGc3gdJcCvC1wbgkag9BmDsFyJAh4RWwjIJJCgaQjhqw7RMCwIkP8pjaH0JZkw3gLDbBsLIfTUgjMGHUKSLA5h3N2GC1nqY%2BRFi4HpLiVkieWRnCSCAA%3D%3D):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class CMyClass {
public:

    CMyClass(int i): m_i{i} {
        instances.push_back(this);
    }

    // ~CMyClass() {
    // ... handle removal if nessesary. check out std::remove(...)
    // }

    int m_i = 0;

    static std::vector<CMyClass*> instances;

    static void reset() {
        for (auto &instance: instances) {
            instance->m_i = 0;
        }
    }
};

std::vector<CMyClass*> CMyClass::instances;

int main() {
    CMyClass myObject1{0};
    CMyClass myObject2{0};

   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

   myObject1.m_i = 1;
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

   myObject2.m_i = 2;
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;

    
   CMyClass::reset();
   cout << myObject1.m_i << endl;
   cout << myObject2.m_i << endl;
}
```

Possible microcontroller (heapless) [implementation](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAJykAA6oCoRODB7evv6p6ZkCIWGRLDFxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5c1bVZDU0EJRHRsXoKjc2teR0jvf1lFRIAlLaoXsTI7Bzm8aHI3lgA1Cbxbk4jxJish9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHTcRMAJ6X13e3XhlGe2YbAUKSYaz2I3Qhystx2TAUCj2bgAsu83AYEQcAOwwm4pLxRWh4ZAgb7fPYUvYAeipewAKggnmxyrE9gA3Jp4JiEp4KBDLWjoQGoAh7GIQxqOZBizCiP6YcmUml7QgqxFeBh4ACOXie/GIe3OyAQezhmNCUwYawAdIqKaFRSwAPp4aFkrEAETdt2%2ByoAklQ9u9lnt5XsWMTiKg0IIo7R6MREWcUgZwQQEHhEQB3QgIX20lFojGIi2NK2YBQmACsFjM1a98VxkJAIFeH0ObkL6PhClIezr8WwKoYlrWlcbZNubNQeCFZyUBD9I7LY4g82xuMpe31ewgTC8RAOZgAbKXDGsQMPRxX1yYcXat1eV5hrc68M8PXsNN6blu716fU9ScbgdcMmFCNcN2Ayk0APZ43A7J9zwra0mAICANHmV8XXgxDXFoH8YOWUUO0Qs9ywUVD0K4LC31wo5DQYdACInH1bkpcixyojDaJww5Py4QiKVgkijjI5dkMotCeOw99SIY/ChNNYj6LcJCKO4mjZNUxjmJ/O1OJQ6StLo/j%2ByUkSdMMqT0Mw7T5LUxTWN/YSVIc9SuOM3i5LEhSmJY3E7XnTBFwkii1wstzfLU6zuLs0zot0gK7Us9zYq8%2BzEqcwLPQ4RZaE4KteD8DgtFIVBOAQyxrAhZZVieTYeFIAhNDyxYAGsQCrDR9E4SRita8rOF4BQQB6lrSry0g4FgGBEBQVAWBSOhYnISg0CWla4mALgzACLA2WJTAADU8EwLMAHkUkYTgmpoWgCFiUaICiQaolCJp3lu3gNrYQQLoYWgvsm0gsBYQxgHEEH8DOBw8DZCtBswVRZQPdYyodGpBqJKI3mINEMHR3gCGIPAWG%2BxYqAMYAFFO86rpu7heH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQQd0DoDCMFBrGsfQ8CiUbYCBdgolQdICFIBG4m4AAOLR5kWVAUjqEdhs6WVdZcJjxnaQImJmQY4g6NIMl1029FtooGEtllrYNuH6lGFpPDaYYakN7pvdduZJm9h2w%2BmUIBjdhYlhWC8aN6jgitIEqyoqjg9lUVXjwAWmPSQ9mAZBpV260zF3XBCBII94ho4nWs10hOu65P%2BtIcm2/T3hM5Gsbmqb6a5ogJBiPxRWKAgDbloTcJWHWHP88L4vS72cuzF4TB8CIUn0D0FnhFEcROcPnm1EGgXSCzN4Ugp5PU57oaOAug8J72VBAyXgui5LsuzArruDwm0Ex1wboPSazdGRMCwHENc7deBdx6k/PutgB4TQ1h1LqPUCocHiANEGqCMFtWTpvNOg0iFN0WMrDIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
class CMyClass {
public:

    // The member variable should not be static because
    // it is unique for each class instance.
    int m_i = 0;
};

// If you use microcontrollers that does not implement the standar library
// replace this with
// CMyClass instances[2];
std::array<CMyClass, 2> instances;

void resetInstances() {
    for (auto &instance: instances) {
        instance.m_i = 0;
    }
}

int main() {

   cout << instances.at(0).m_i << endl;
   cout << instances.at(1).m_i << endl;

   instances.at(0).m_i = 1;
   cout << instances.at(0).m_i << endl;
   cout << instances.at(1).m_i << endl;

   instances.at(1).m_i = 2;
   cout << instances.at(0).m_i << endl;
   cout << instances.at(1).m_i << endl;

   resetInstances();
   cout << instances.at(0).m_i << endl;
   cout << instances.at(1).m_i << endl;
}
```

Note: I do not recommend using the name convention with `m_` for public class members. In this case i would call the member variable `m_i` for simply `i` and then use `m_...` for private variables that is only used in private functions of the class.

Comment: the output is: 
```c++
0
0
1
0
1
2
1
2
``` 
expected 
```c++
0
0
1
0
1
2
0
0
```

Comment: I think your `CMyClass` ctor should add the object to `instances` (and dtor remove it). At the moment it is not populated.

Comment: @wohlstad yes you're right, I missed that.

Comment: Works like a charm!
Could it be done without using vectors? (Vectors are heavy for MCU)

Comment: @OlegGolevych You need some way to keep track of the instances, so somhow for the usecase you have described with separate variables for each instances but where you can reset them both you need to keep a list of all the instances. You could of course have a static variable that overrides the other variables, but that seems to be a bit of topic. I will add another vector example for reference.

Comment: @OlegGolevych Now I added a version that does not use heap allocations, I did not know that it was a requirement from the start.

Comment: @Lasersköld, sorry, it's my mistake that I did not describe the application aspects in more detail. Uncommenting CMyClass instances[2]; gives errors

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I just added a explanation for that. Some Arduino versions (or most) does not allow you to use the standard library, even though std::array is perfectly usable on a microcontroller

Comment: yes your edit just came a second after my quesiton

Comment: @OlegGolevych Yes, you would need to change `instances.at(1)` to `instances[1]` etc. But now i have made a million changes to this question. If the concept helps please accept the question or at least vote it up.

Comment: As I mentioned above, also your `CMyClass` **dtor** should **remove** the instance from the vector/array.

Comment: @Lasersköld, works like a charm! Many thanks! This will help to finalize my Universal byte-by-byte receive method on [GitHub](https://github.com/Siegurd01/Universal-byte-by-byte-receive-method). Maybe one day it become a standard for unprotected lines data sending/receiving.

Comment: @wohlstad Nothing in the question indicates that the classes is ever deleted. In the question they are defined as global variables.

Comment: @OlegGolevych Nice to hear, and interesting to se what project you are using it for :)

Comment: @Lasersköld it may be so in the OP's [mre], but a proper and more robust solution for tracking the exising instances must also take into accout objects destruction. Tomorrow this piece of code might be modified so that the instances are not global. If it's easy to solve the problem in a more complete and robust way - why not do it ?

Comment: @wohlstad But in this case the solution is to move the array into `main()` and the problem is solved. But I'm arguing about my second example though. I could add the destructor code for the std::vector version of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements:

> *How to make the variable m_i have its own value for each object, and
> when a certain function is called, the value of m_i for all objects
> should be set to zero, no matter how many objects of the class
> CMyClass were created*

These are 2 requirements that **cannot be both fulfilled trivially**:

1. If `int m_i` is a static member, it will be "shared" between all instances (requirement 1 not fulfilled).
2. If `int m_i` is a non-static member, each object can have its own value. But a method cannot trivially set it for all instances (requirement 2 not fulfilled).

**The solution:**

Keep a static array of instances. Your **ctor** should **add** the object to this array, and the **dtor** should **remove** it.
Thus each object can have its own value of `m_i`, but a specific method can iterate over the said array and set it for all instances.